# How to create multiple Vms using terraform libvirt provider?

Tags: terraform, libvirt

I just want to know How to create multiple Vms using terraform libvirt provider ?
I managed to create one vm , is there a way to do it in one tf file

```
# libvirt.tf
# add the provider
provider "libvirt" {
    uri = "qemu:///system"
}
#create pool
resource "libvirt_pool" "ubuntu" {
    name = "ubuntu-pool"
    type = "dir"
    path = "/libvirt_images/ubuntu_pool/"
}
# create image
resource "libvirt_volume" "image-qcow2" {
    name = "ubuntu-amd64.qcow2"
    pool = libvirt_pool.ubuntu.name
    source ="${path.module}/downloads/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"
    format = "qcow2"

}
```

I used cloud config to define the user and ssh connection

I want to complete this code so I can create multiple VM

Comment: Have you looked at how you create multiple resources at a time with Terraform in general? Particularly looking at `count` and `for_each`?

Comment: I used 'count' but I got multiple errors .. I just want to know the exact wait

Comment: If you tried something and got errors you should also edit your question to show the failing code and the errors. This allows people to see exactly what you've tried and point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: '# create image
resource "libvirt_volume" "image-qcow2" {
 name = "ubuntu-amd64-${count.index}.qcow2"
 pool = libvirt_pool.ubuntu.name
 source ="${path.module}/downloads/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img"
 format = "qcow2"
 count = 2

}'

Comment: error is Error: Missing resource instance key

  on libvirt.tf line 16, in resource "libvirt_volume" "image-qcow2":
  16:  pool = libvirt_pool.ubuntu.name

Because libvirt_pool.ubuntu has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed
on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    libvirt_pool.ubuntu[count.index]

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the code and the errors? Don't attempt to put code or errors in comments because it's basically impossible to read them. Plus the question should contain everything needed to understand the problem. Comments are only for guiding how to improve the question or help improve understanding and aren't first class citizens in Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I just Added [count.index] in ubunto pool instance and it works thank you